# Is there a clean-URL-reflective version of file_create_url()?

Tags: testing, uri, files

I have a site with clean URLs enabled and in a test I've written, I compare the current `drupalGetHeader('location')` to `file_create_url($file->uri)`. The tests passes on my site, but on the qa.drupal.org testbot (and, presumably, on any site that doesn't have clean URLs enabled) the test fails.

Is there an API function that's more clean-URL-reflective to `file_create_url()`?

Comment: With `DrupalPublicStreamWrapper`, the URL returned from `DrupalPublicStreamWrapper::getExternalUrl()` doesn't contain ?q=. I would say it is already clean-URLs agnostic.

Comment: It doesn't create a usable URL if clean URLs are enabled though, since it creates something other than the actual path.

Comment: Since it is the URL for an actual file, it doesn't need to use the 'q' query parameter. If you have a file in sites/default/files, its URL is always `http://<domain.name>/sites/default/files/<filename>` whenever clean URLs are enabled, or not.

Comment: That makes sense. It is odd, then, that drupalGetHeader() returns a url with ?q= in it. Could this be an artifact of the redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using

```
str_replace('/?q=', '/'drupalGetHeader('location'));
```

So basically I gave up on including the `?q=` that appears in the URL and instead stripped it from everything. It seems a little messy but it works for my purpose. Still doesn't really answer the question though.

[`drupal_parse_url()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_parse_url/7) looked promising at first, but it didn't work because

`drupal_parse_url(file_create_url($uri))` returned 'path' = `http://example.com/path/to/file`

but

`drupal_parse_url(drupal_get_headers('location'))` returned simply 'path' = `/path/to/file`